Is there a way to find the name of a missing font from the system used in an Inkscape project?
The font toolbar only says that a "sans-serif" font is missing.

I think this is possibly a bug in 1.3 see bug report here.  To fix it, just choose "Sans" instead.

It seems that the issue is not associated with that bug, it occurs with Inkscape 1.1. I updated to 1.4 and the issue persisted. I set "Sans" to the unformatted text and the style is not the expected. It is even different from the font preview shown at the bottom of the Text and Font panel. Confuse...

1.4 is in still in beta. The current stable release is 1.3.2. The bug may have also existed in earlier versions, and might even exist in the beta.  Setting "Sans" as the font works for me in 1.3.2. The font matches the style shown in the Font panel for me. As to when it will be fixed, I don't know. It's tagged as "low priority".
